# VBA Excel Toggle Button: With 10 rows, how do I unhide each row separately and not in a group?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working in VBA and Excel 2007 with active control toggle button, which I'm trying to figure out how to get to function the way I need it to. Will someone please help me out?

This works for only unhiding a single row at a time for two hidden rows:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

If ToggleButton1 Then
   Rows(76).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
   Rows(77).EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If

End Sub
```

This does not work for only unhiding a single row at a time for more than two hidden rows:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

If ToggleButton1 Then
   Rows(76).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
   Rows(77).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
   Rows(78).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

What do I need to do to get this to work? This is all I need the toggle button to do. Each row has identical information (text fields, field names, etc.), but I need each row to only become visible upon clicking just one toggle button. I know multiple toggle buttons will works like a breeze, but I really am wanting to just use one toggle button to unhide each row, one at a time. By default, the rows will be hidden first, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a counter and then count down and you should be able to do what you are looking for. In this example if the counter is 0 we hide the rows 1-3 and then show each row untill we are back to 0 and then hide them again when we click the button.

```
Dim counter As Integer
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
If counter = 0 Then
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows(2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows(3).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    counter = 3
Else
    Rows(counter).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    counter = counter - 1
End If



End Sub
```

Hope it helps
//KH

Comment: Man you and L42 responded and faster than folks at a VBA Excel forum *smh*. Thanks for responding. Strange how I tried this before going to sleep and it didn't work. But after waking up and trying it again, I can now saw it works like a charm!! You rock! Thanks a lot Karl!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim myrow As Range

Set rng = Me.Rows("75:85")

If Me.ToggleButton1 Then
    For Each myrow In rng
        If Not myrow.Hidden Then
            myrow.Hidden = True
            If myrow.row = 85 Then
                myrow.Offset(-10, 0).Hidden = False
            Else
                myrow.Offset(1, 0).Hidden = False
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

This hides and unhides `Rows76-85` simultaneously.
You start with all 10 Rows hidden.
After 1st click, `Row 76` will appear and so on.
All will be hidden again after `Row 85` was shown.
I used 10 rows based on your question title, adjust it to suit your needs.

**Edit1:**

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim myrow As Range

Set rng = Me.Rows("76:85")

If Me.ToggleButton1 Then
    For Each myrow In rng
        If myrow.Hidden Then
            myrow.Hidden = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    rng.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

Above will work as you want it.
Although you already accepted an answer, I still would want to correct my code.
At least for you and others reference.

Comment: Thanks for a such a fast response. I appreciate your code because it definitely works. The only thing that it wasn't doing as it made a row unhide was not showing the previous unhidden row in an accordian-like style (if that makes sense). I could definitely use this code for a survey or quiz sheet. Thanks for your expertise, too, man!!

Comment: @Bari Ah I misunderstood your requirement. If I'd known, what you want is a lot easier. Anyways glad you got your answer.